# Mismatched interface and implementation signature

Tags: java, jar, interface

What happens if a jar has an interface with a method implemented by a class in a different jar, and the interface added throwing checked exception and deployed without recompiling the implementation class?

Comment: A very good question.  One of those rare ones that made me think for a little while after using Java for over 15 years.  Still, if I caught you doing this on my team, I'd summarize it like this "Don't do it again."

Answer (score 0):

I understand that one might think it would be in the best interests for the class loader to balk at not capturing the exception in the header and making you declare that you throw it in the implementation.

However, this is valid Java

```
public interface GetFive {

  int getFive() throws Exception;

}

public class GetFiveImpl implements GetFive {

  int getFive() {
     return 5;
  }
}
```

It is valid because you aren't required to throw an exception, even if your interface indicates you could.

What is not valid is using `GetFive.getFive()` in a block that doesn't catch the exception.  `GetFiveImpl.getFive()` in a block theat doesn't catch the exception is fine.

Even if you had a block that worked on the interface, that block was compiled in an environment where the exception could never be raised; so, it would work just fine.  Still, I wouldn't make this a common practice.

I tested this, and the results confirm my suspicions.  This doesn't mean it is a good idea to ever do this; however, after thinking about this for some time, it's not possible for the dependent jar to throw the exception without recompiling anyway, which would recheck the interface.